# Fitting an image to a div container in HTML

Tags: html, css

I would like an image to fit into a div container. It should fit even if the image is smaller than div or image is larger than div. I have tried some options like setting max-width and height to 100% but it doesn't work.

```css
#content {
  width: 351px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img src="https://dumkhum.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SHIVAAY_ISHQAA_1.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is my code link:https://jsfiddle.net/w8r0g921/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content {
  width:351px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#content img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id = "content">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
  background-image: url(https://dumkhum.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SHIVAAY_ISHQAA_1.jpg);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  width:351px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Just have the image be the background of the div, then control how it looks with the background-position property. Hope this helps you.